# "Fetching..." Message In MySQL Workbench Object Browser

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

when I click on a database in the "Object Browser" section of my MySQL Workbench to see its schema, I get lines that display the message "fetching...".  The object browser hangs on this and the schema of the database is never displayed.  I get the same error on different servers.  Does anybody know how to remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this exact same issue on OSX / XAMPP and figured out that the permissions on my MySQL config file were the ultimate culprit.  See the [details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127538/mysql-workbench-fetching-cannot-browse-db).

Answer (score 0):

It seems Workbench is an easy to hang app. Try testing your connections from a console.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks bmoeskau for your answer.  The 'fetching' message actually disappeared a couple of weeks after I posted this question after I installed a new version of Workbench.  I am not sure what version of Workbench is included in the XAMPP stack, but the Workbench included in this package is usually not the latest release.