# MySQL Workbench "fetching..." -- cannot browse DB

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp

I've been having a lot of issues lately, basically since the last time I upgraded XAMPP for OSX (v1.7.3) and/or my MySQL GUI tools.  Using [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) (v5.2.44), I can connect to the DB running in XAMPP just fine, but trying to browse any database, under tables/views/etc it only shows "Fetching..." and never shows anything else.  I can actually query tables, which is interesting, but I can't actually manage the databases in any meaningful way.

Googling, [others](http://engin.bzzzt.biz/2011/04/06/mysql-workbench-fetching-problem-solved/) reported having luck running `mysql_upgrade` on the command line, which ran fine but did not fix my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link above to `mysql_upgrade` did not solve my problem directly, but it did lead me to examine my mysql error file, which ultimately led me to the solution.  I noticed several lines like this in the error file (located at `[xampp root]/var/mysql/[dbname].err`):

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/sbin/mysqld: Can't create/write to file 
    '/var/folders/y2/37h93r_931sdfpcr7vnc83380000gn/T/ibigNFFi' (Errcode: 13)
```

That led me to [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cannot-create.html) in the MySQL docs which states that you should explicitly set the temp folder for MySQL.  I double-checked my config file (`[xampp root]/etc/my.cnf`) and saw this, which looked fine:

```
[mysqld]
tmpdir = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/
```

However, looking back at the error log, I also noticed this:

```
Warning: World-writable config file '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf' is ignored
```

Duh. The config file was getting ignored, so the configured temp folder was not getting used (I have no clue why the file was world-writeable...).  I edited permissions on the `my.cnf` file which was 777 and simply removed the "Everyone|write" permission (now 775 / -rwxrwxr-x), reloaded everything, and now everything works.

Not a very intuitive symptom for the ultimate fix, so hopefully this helps someone else.

Answer (score 13):

The following command worked for me on windows:

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin>mysql_upgrade.exe -u root -p --force

If the root password is not set, you might need to do this before you run the command above:

mysql>  SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' =  PASSWORD('something');

Comment: You don't have to set root password to run mysql_upgrade, simply omit "-u" switch.

Comment: worked in my case (Mint 16 + MySQL 5.5.34). Only I needed to run it with `sudo`

Comment: ArchLinux, had to do this with when MariaDB updated. Also had to use `sudo`. Didn't use `--force`.

Comment: I needed to stop the server, close MySQL workbench, find the executable and run it manually from it's directory, then restart the server. Some messages about finding upgrades was then in the startup logs. But still worked!

Answer (score 1):

If you have MAMP instead of XAMP the solution above won't work for you.
Open MAMP then on the top menu go to Tools->Upgrade MySQL databases.
Now open Mysql Workbench and it should list all your tables correctly

Answer (score 1):

If you are using linux distro the run following command:

```
mysql_upgrade -u root -p
```

Comment: worked for me.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I set Authenticated Users with all privileges to the var/folders/y2/
For me work fine ;)

Before the process I removed authenticated users privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Close and reopen Workbench. it worked for me.

Stop server.

close workbench window

start server

open workbench window

worked for me .. windows 64bit

Answer (score 0):

I had that error with MySQL 8, win10. I've noticed that this line [Where the error was](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBTiR.png)

Was leading to another directory trying to find the my.ini file. Looked for it, found it in that directory, changed it. Opened Workbench, clik on every item that was in gray, and turned it into black and that's it!! Ok now!!