# MySQL Workbench Object Browser not working

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have ( I believe ) successfully installed Mysql Version 5.6.10.1 on Windows 7 using MySQL Installer which contains MySQL Workbench in it.

The setup also has some sample data. ( Sample databases and tables. )

When I use the commandline (mysq.exe) I can see the db 's and tables just fine. Also when I use Navicat Lite, there are no problems..

However, when I use MySQL Workbench **Tables Fetching** message stays forever on the screen for databases. Please see the screenshot:

[image: Tables fetching...]

I can run queries on MySQL Workbench as well such as

SELECT WORLD; SHOW TABLES; etc... and they will also work just fine..

However, what is wrong with Object Browser?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Fetching..." Message In MySQL Workbench Object Browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637023/fetching-message-in-mysql-workbench-object-browser)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Workbench “fetching…” — cannot browse DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13127538/mysql-workbench-fetching-cannot-browse-db)

Comment: Hello, it is not answered there. The solution simple is a newer version of the Workbench. My Workbench is the newest.

Comment: Also, I have nothing to do with XAMPP.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO What is it related to?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO Perhaps before downvoting the question/linking it to unrelated questions that just look similar and voting for close, you may want to actually read this question and the question you are linking to, and better help if you have the required information?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I resolved my problem:

mysql_update was not working for me for some reason. I was getting many errors saying "File not found..." so that did not work.

I uninstalled MYSQL Server. 
I deleted everything related to Mysql from both Program Files and Program Files(x86)
I deleted everything related to Mysql from folder c:\ProgramData

Then, I re-installed MySql using MySQL installer.

Problem solved.

Comment: The problem is that this is killing a ant with a flamethrower.

Comment: This isn't solution. Its like saying I cannot unzip a zip file and the way to resolve it is to reinstall Windows.  Its way overkill. BTW, this also happened when the server is installed in Ubuntu.

Comment: @riahc3 You are welcome to provide a better answer?

Comment: I came here looking for a answer but this is not a answer. This is simply trying to restart from scratch. This is not a answer, it is simply restarting from scratch.